# How to Validate Color Coded Background in a table using Selenium Web Driver / Java

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, colors

I wanted to validate the Color Coded Background inside a Table for a specific Value. The Color code is background-color:rgb(96,192,96).I have 5 different links on the page. Each link has the same background color. I need to validate weather the background color is displayed as rgb(96,192,96) for each of the links. If the color code is anything other the rgb(96,192,96), then the code should consider that the link/server is down.

The five Values/Link That Display on the page are Ssi-1-a, Ssi-2-a, Ssi-3-a, Ssi-4-a and Ssi-5-a

How can I validate this using Xpath or any other method ? Provided the Code Below

```
<html>
    <head>
    <body>
        <b>Status as of </b>
        Wed Oct 25 16:57:57 2017
        <br/>
        <br/>
        This page shows the current version and build date of the SSI code loaded into the JVMs that constitute the environment
        you selected.
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div style="float:left">
            <table style="display:inline-table" width="500" border="1">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                <tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Prod</th>
                    <td style="background-color:rgb(96,192,96)" align="center">
                        <a href="https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXX.net:XXXXXX/ssiadmin/">Ssi-1-a</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <tr>
                <tr>
                <tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a screenshot and asset the color of a pixel at the targeted location. You could also check the computed style with `driver.findElement(...).getCssValue("background-color")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use getAttribute method of WebElement, to analyze the value of style attribute. The following code should give you a rough idea of how to do it:

```
WebElement linkToCheck = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpathOfTheLink"));
if(!linkToCheck.getAttribute("style").contains("rgb(96,192,96)")){
    // server is down, --> does some action
}
```

where `xpathOfTheLink` is the xpath of the link you want to check. Given you have 5 different links, you will have to create 5 xpath, or use a dynamic xpath allowing you to check every xpath in a loop, using the code above.

Be carefull, because as mentionned here https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute-java.lang.String- :

> The "style" attribute is converted as best can be to a text representation with a trailing semi-colon.

Therefore maybe you will have to check if it contains something else than "rgb(96,192,96)". I let you try, or provide an url with the given html, so I can try (I am curious to see the result).

Comment: This will only work if the style is fixed in the component, if you are using a css class will not work, because the css stays external to the DOM

Comment: Thank You. I have used it like below and it is working.


WebElement linkToCheck = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td"));

 
String Colorcode = linkToCheck.getCssValue("background-color");

System.out.println(Colorcode);

if (linkToCheck.getCssValue("background-color").contains("rgba(96, 192, 96, 1)"))
    {
System.out.println("I can see the Color");
  
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/a")).click();
    }
    else
{
    System.out.println("I cannot see the Color - Existing the Code");
    }

Comment: How can i use  a dynamic xpath alowwing you to check every xpath in loop?

Comment: 1) You need to find an xpath that will point to your 5 links. This xpath will probably use what is in common in localization of your 5 links. 2) You will need to use `driver.findElements(xpathToAllFiveElements)` that return a list of webElement and 3) In a loop, you access your links one after the other, thanks to the list of webElement you have.

Answer (score 2):

```
driver.findElement(By.name("nameOfComponent")).getCssValue("background-color");
```